# Manually calculate the boxplot whiskers in altair

Tags: python, altair

I'm looking for a way to find the values of the boxplot whiskers, manually, within altair itself (so without adding an extra column in the dataframe).

Below is a plot I'm trying to create. The orange area should align with the boxplot whiskers, so the first value of 'x' inside the 1.5*iqr range.

I have been playing around with vega expressions (inrange, clampRange ...) but could not find a way to do so.

[image: plot]

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9p3NATABDccgDaoADZKAnpgBOKDSAC2S-QGs8IQjoAOmFCABGEAB53NEcd0xvCmEQoAIwAdACs3BSEmlj6lCiE+qSY3MRgFgnISSlyIIGQdCRIqCBu1vCYmnRO5Wn2jsggAI6kSkRwhCpwaI6ycqBmlta2Dk5gcPpgmo7ckF6GTc7aGSDclHAAXo3BAExseQUQRVAloOWlldW1ayCUyjPW2-oQKDBKmpSYeaONLW0dLrEXogfoAXQGIG0ekWxiGVlKvyc+kwYB8PAWyMwNUOUEKxWsF1AVxqTTcJhItyRTVa7WIQJ6fW4bl2FSw1zJZnKsjS+nalBgEH0JiMoCUCAQKIQKkaxggdicFKgtxJN24SiyZSVoM4oHliqUdRAqrJtw1tS5oIhYO42HoTBCHAOutM5gRoGpIBRaNu8yFTiF7QQTPyeOOBNKRON7NJLTYVIaTlpgO6ILyLLZVVjzWCHFBPz5UAFQpF6jFEqlMtFIH1NOCKpjapA5rrOr1CppEgbWabLZaXekEJdDzApG0AScAAo6CpSCZQs0JAACAC0S5nhDnC+CAEozZq4M1DJCR2Oq01p7P5znV0vL5v54f9EuAFRLsLhHd79Wa5rxk8fKO45-PeW6LkuADUd4bluT6vu+ERfvuSa5v+Q6DG6IyJk03ron6ixQnAJghkcJxnGU1jipKmDShOrbcCaFH1GMNIAvSqYhhmpRUZWdH9t2HIUf0LrwlhLHgJM0yzBi-pLCsVjrFsOz7Li+KnISmaCUa9wfI0oDPK8yDvJ83zMX8ybscCfSyNa3Abko1hQEoxFOPZK7OEo7zBAA7LsMCYAAbAF7DecoYAAJwABwsOFdABc44QwCwMUSGAIYopQECaCCpQ6Y8kZOJQjDmNi+bcAAJPcjCYGYThiIQdiUMgAD0zW9NKoQIJ0jCkM4oRwBAzVVTVShtTRSgrrEARtSwoQ+aEbChAAVplyp2SoGqYIQWSgG5Hleb5-lBSFYVRTFcUJUlKVpdWFzOuckiQhcs0sE9rARG9yCzQFn3hJ93mDrIQA)

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

values =  [0, 3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 5, 7]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': values})

points = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(color='black', size=120).encode(
    x=alt.X('x:Q', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
)

boxplot = alt.Chart(df).mark_boxplot(ticks=True, extent=1.5, outliers=True).encode(
    x='x:Q',
)

iqr = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect(color='lime').encode(
    x='q1(x):Q',
    x2='q3(x):Q'
)

whiskers = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect(color='orange').transform_aggregate(
    q1='q1(x)',
    q3='q3(x)',
).transform_calculate(
    iqr=alt.datum.q3 - alt.datum.q1,
    q0=alt.datum.q1 - (alt.datum.iqr * 1.5),
    q100=alt.datum.q3 + (alt.datum.iqr * 1.5),
).encode(
    x='q0:Q',
    x2='q100:Q',
)

minmax = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect(color='red').transform_aggregate(
    xmin='min(x)',
    xmax='max(x)'
).encode(
    x='xmin:Q',
    x2='xmax:Q',
).properties(width=1000)


((boxplot + points) & (minmax + whiskers + iqr + points)).resolve_scale(x='shared')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is to be able to use the aggregate values of the quartiles to filter the original data. When you use `transform_aggregate` you are reducing the dataframe to only include the aggregate values you are creating. If you instead use `transform_joinaggregate` you are joining the aggregate values to the original dataframe, which means that you can then use `transform_filter` to return the max and min original data points within the bounds of the q1/q3 -/+ 1.5 * IQR:

```
whiskers = alt.Chart(df).mark_rect(color='orange').transform_joinaggregate(
    q1='q1(x)',
    q3='q3(x)',
).transform_calculate(
    iqr='datum.q3 - datum.q1'
).transform_filter(
    # VL concatenates these strings so we can split
    # them on two lines to improve readability
    'datum.x < (datum.q3 + datum.iqr * 1.5)'
    '&& datum.x > (datum.q1 - datum.iqr * 1.5)'
).encode(
    x='min(x)',
    x2='max(x)',
)
```

[image]